# C# replace with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

This code doesn't work, but it works with other expressions, like `(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)`.

The below expression works correctley in a regular expression tester, but it doesn't replace Hello with id in this code:

```
string test = "int Hello :=   2 ;";
string pattern = "\b(?!int|bool)(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)\b";
string replacement = "Id";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string newline = rgx.Replace(test, replacement);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should escape `backslashes` or use `@` beginning of your `string` and make it `verbatim string`. `\b` has a special meaning in `C#` which is `backspace`, see documentation:  [`Escape Sequences`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

```
string pattern = @"\b(?!int|bool)(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)\b";
```